# Отрисовка градиентов

Tags: css, css3, svg

Возможно ли реализовать градиент на элементе подобного вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь присутствует как срез углов, градиент линейный от темного к светлому, так еще и смена цвета линиями повторяющимися по пикселей 5.

Или же вообще не заморачиваться подобной фигней и вставить фон как png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главная проблема - это не сам градиент, а его адаптивность, и тут проблема... Для фиксированных размеров всё просто:

```css
body { background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'); }

.grad {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.grad:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 450%;
  width: inherit;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07) 0px, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07) 10px, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10px, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20px), 
    linear-gradient(180deg, 
      #b7df67, 
      #00af01);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: translate(0%, -39%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
```

Comment: Так а в в чём проблема с адаптивностью? Уголки только?

Comment: @zhurof они самые. Но, они напрямую зависят от размера контейнера, и есть подозрение, что простыми вычислениями непосредственно в CSS тут не обойтись.

Comment: Можно через директиву `@supports` добавить вариант с `clip-path`. В разрешениях, на которых будет видна разница всё равно в `IE` никто не смотрит

Comment: @zhurof ty спорю. Наверняка есть решения, но я пока сам не сталкивался. Если добавите свой вариант, то с меня плюс.

Comment: Использовал `@supports` для браузеров где не используется `clip-path` и сделал `background` изображением, вроде встает неплохо

Comment: @Алексей , `@supports` нужно наоборот использовать там, где `clip-path` поддерживается.  В том же IE не поддерживается ни `clip-path` ни `@supports`

Comment: @zhurof Да именно так и сделал, затроил и не правильно выразился. Сделал фон изображением и ниже приписал что если `clip-path` поддерживается то использовать его